# Produce a line tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

Is there a way to produce the segment using the following code to draw a line A-B plus 1cm to a point C, obviously without calculating the coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,3){B}

    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
    \tkzLabelPoints(A,B)

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,3){B}
    \tkzDefPointWith[linear normed,K=-1](B,A)  
    \tkzGetPoint{C}
    \tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
    \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Another possibility

```
 \tkzDefPointWith[colinear= at B,normed](A,B)
```

Note that if you want C to be aligned with A and B, you'll have to make a calculation to determine the slope of (AB). In general, the principle here is to divide the vector AB by its norm.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This code uses `\tkzDefPointBy[translation=from A to B](1,0)` to create point C located 1cm beyond point B along the line AB. This avoids the need for orthogonal vector calculations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,3){B}

    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
    \tkzLabelPoints(A,B)

    % Extend the line segment AB by 1cm to create point C
    \tkzDefPointBy[translation=from A to B](1,0)
    \tkzGetPoint{C}

    \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
    \tkzDrawPoint(C)
    \tkzLabelPoints(C)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]